# Behaviors.Forms Command not Executing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to upgrade an existing Xamarin project to the latest versions of various libraries. The Xamarin forms themselves live in a shared library. My page has a ListView on it & I am attempting to capture the event fired when an item is 'chosen'. However, the ICommand in my ViewModel is not executing.

NOTES:

- I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.8...but had to downgrade Behaviors.Forms to 1.3 because the code is in a .NET Standard library.
- If I upgrade to Behaviors.Forms 1.4 a design-time error occurs (see photo below)

**SHARED LIBRARY INFORMATION:**
.NET Standard 2.0

- Acr.UserDialogs Version="7.1.0.454"
- AzureMobileClient.Helpers Version="4.0.2.507-pre"
- Behaviors.Forms Version="1.3.0"
- Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie Version="3.1.3"
- Prism.DryIoc.Forms Version="8.0.0.1850-pre"
- Prism.Forms Version="8.0.0.1850-pre"
- Refractored.MvvmHelpers Version="1.6.2"
- Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.Common Version="2020.2.624.1"
- Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataControls Version="2020.2.624.1"
- Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataGrid Version="2020.2.624.1"
- Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.Primitives Version="2020.2.624.1"
- Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.SkiaSharp Version="2020.2.624.1"
- Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms Version="2.4.11.982"
- Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms Version="2.4.11.982"
- Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations Version="2.4.11.982"
- Xamarin.Forms Version="4.8.0.1364"

**CONVERTER CLASS:**
The original programmer returns 'ItemTapped' EventArgs...

```
public class SelectedItemEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region <Methods>

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var eventArgs = value as ItemTappedEventArgs;
        return eventArgs != null ? eventArgs.Item : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 

    #endregion
}
```

**VIEW MODEL:**
The ListView binds-up & displays items (see photo's below)...

```
using CustomControls;
using Models;
using MvvmHelpers.Commands;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Prism.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Constructors

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService, IDeviceService deviceService) : base(navigationService, pageDialogService, deviceService)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    #endregion

    #region <Properties>

    public AccordionNode ShakeoutListItemsAccordion { get; private set; }

    public Command<SimpleListItem> OnShakeoutListItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

    public List<SimpleListItem> ShakeoutListItems { get; private set; } = new List<SimpleListItem>();

    #endregion

    #region <Events>

    public async void OnShakeoutListItemSelected(SimpleListItem item)
    {
        if (item.Name == "Add Shakeout")
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("ShakeoutDocumentGeneratorPage");
    }

    #endregion

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Commands
        OnShakeoutListItemSelectedCommand = new Command<SimpleListItem>(OnShakeoutListItemSelected);

        // Accordians
        ShakeoutListItemsAccordion = new AccordionNode("OverwrittenInView", GlobalVariables.Accordion.Height, GlobalVariables.Accordion.HeaderBackgroundColor, GlobalVariables.Accordion.HeaderColorTextColor, GlobalVariables.Accordion.SeparatorColor);

        // Data
        ShakeoutListItems.Add(new SimpleListItem { Name = "Add Shakeout", Title = string.Empty, Type = string.Empty });
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**
Because the converter-class 'ItemTapped' EventArgs, I am focusing-on that event...but I can chane this (if needed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:BaseContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Behaviors;assembly=Behaviors"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.Converters;assembly=ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.CustomControls;assembly=ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.Helpers;assembly=ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.Views;assembly=ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile"
             x:Class="ETC.Operations.Pulse.Mobile.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:SelectedItemEventArgsConverter x:Key="EventToCommand"/>
            <forms:SvgImageSourceConverter x:Key="SvgImageSourceConverter"></forms:SvgImageSourceConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0">

                <!-- SHAKEOUTS -->
                <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0"  Style="{DynamicResource AccordionTitleStyle}">
                    <StackLayout Style="{DynamicResource AccordionHeaderStackLayoutStyle}">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShakeoutListItemsAccordion.ExpandContractAccordion}"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Shakeouts" Style="{DynamicResource AccordionHeaderTextStyle}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label TextColor="{Binding ShakeoutListItemsAccordion.HeaderTextColor}"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="{Binding ShakeoutListItemsAccordion.IconText}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="{Binding ShakeoutListItemsAccordion.LineColor}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
                </StackLayout>

                <!-- SHAKEOUTS: Controls -->
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}" HeightRequest="200" IsVisible="{Binding ShakeoutListItemsAccordion.IsExpanded}" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="lvShakeoutListItems"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ShakeoutListItems}"
                        RowHeight="40">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid Style="{DynamicResource ListViewGridItemStyle}" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="13,0,0,0">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewLabelCenterRowLeft}" TextColor="{StaticResource LabelValueTextColor}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="ItemTapped">
                                <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnShakeoutListItemSelectedCommand}" Converter="{StaticResource EventToCommand}" />
                            </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
                        </ListView.Behaviors>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</views:BaseContentPage>
```

**PHONE IMAGES:**
As you can see...the ViewModel is binding to data.

[image]

NOTES:
Upgrading to Behaviors.Forms 1.4 generates a design-time error.

[image]

**UPDATES:**
Here are my updates on the suggestions being made by contributors...

- The 'Tap gesture on main cell object' option does not fire an event (at all)
- The 'selected Item' event raises...but does not call the "MainPageViewModel OnShakeoutListItemSelected" event
- I am currently looking at "Corcav Behavior" in NuGet

Comment: I test the code you provided and reproduce the error. For the Behaviors.Forms 1.4, this issue has be reported and would not be fixed now. You could follow the link below or open a new issue on GitHub. https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/issues/22 Please use the Behaviors.Forms 1.3 instead.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I am using Behaviors.Forms 1.3

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** : Use tap gesture on main cell object

```
<ListView
                        x:Name="lvShakeoutListItems"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ShakeoutListItems}"
                        RowHeight="40">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Style="{DynamicResource ListViewGridItemStyle}" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="13,0,0,0">
                            **<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnShakeoutListItemSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>**
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewLabelCenterRowLeft}" TextColor="{StaticResource LabelValueTextColor}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Option 2**: Use selected Item on main cell object

```
<ListView
                        x:Name="lvShakeoutListItems"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ShakeoutListItems}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelctedItem}"
                        RowHeight="40">
...
</>
```

**Option 3** : Use corcav behavior nuget to get event to command behavior

Comment: Please see the UPDATES SECTIO0N I added to my question (above)

Comment: for 

**option 1** : Event is being fired (I think) but due to BindingContext it is not being captured, Try by using in code behind.
**option 2** : it is being raised , you have the object you selected , you can manually raise/call the function in the setter of the selected item